# How to remove ' symbol from a str?

Tags: python, string

I have a sentence that is "I don't want to do it anymore". What I am aiming to do is to change the **(')** symbol in "don't" word to **"%27"**. I have tried using replace() method or the method below but they didn't work for me.

```
words = text.lower().split(' ')
for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "".join(" ' "):
            letter = "%27"
```

I know the answer must be simple but I can't find it

Comment: What was the problem with replace? That's exactly how to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to do URL encoding? It sounds like you should use `requests` and let it handle encoding for you, or at least use the dedicated functions in `urllib` for URL encoding.

Comment: Also, what was the intent behind `"".join(" ' ")`? It sounds like you have some pretty bad misperceptions about how strings work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `replace` on your entire string:

```
>>> sentence = "I don't want to do it anymore"
>>> sentence.replace("'", "%27")
'I don%27t want to do it anymore'
```

`replace("'", "%27")` replaces all occurrences of `'` with `%27` in your sentence. No need to iterate over each word individually.

---

If what you are trying to do is to encode the entire string and also replace spaces and other special characters, then perhaps [**`urllib.parse.quote`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) is what you want:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> sentence = "I don't want to do it anymore"
>>> quote(sentence)
'I%20don%27t%20want%20to%20do%20it%20anymore'
```

---

If you need `+` instead of `%20` for spaces use [**`urllib.parse.quote_plus`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) instead:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
>>> sentence = "I don't want to do it anymore"
>>> quote_plus(sentence)
'I+don%27t+want+to+do+it+anymore'
```

Comment: thank you and you are right about the quote thing but instead of %20 they use + which is why i didn't use quote func

Comment: @ResulBulbul: Whoever "they" are, they should accept `%20`. If they don't, that's a bug.

Comment: There's a method for that as well :) I just updated my answer.

Comment: you're welcome! glad I was able to help. if my answer solved your problem please don't forget to accept it :)